# Fuelphp - Use dump() in twig template

Tags: twig, fuelphp

I'm trying to activate twig's useful "dump()" method but can't seem to find a way to do it in fuelphp.
Anybody knows how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very easy to do,

Just add twig as dependency requirement in your composer like

```
"twig/twig": "1.14.1"
```

and later run

```
php composer.phar update
```

and after that

open your config.php file in config/config.php and uncomment always_load array and also uncomment package array with always_load array . Your final always_load array should look somewhat like this

```
'always_load' => array(
    'packages' => array(
        'parser',
    ),
),
```

Thats all twig is activated, you can use methods with in your controller and actions.